# Listview displaying only last element throughout

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in an activity, I have created custom listview for the same. In the custom list, I have an imageview and two textview. When am adding values to the list, but it displays only the last element throughout.

```
public class ContactUs extends Activity {
ImageView imageView;
TextView tvDetails,tv1;
private static String details[] = {"details1","details2","details3","details4","details5","details6"};
private static String desc[] = {"Name","Call","Email",
        "Skype","Head Office","Website"};

private static int icons[] = {R.drawable.user, R.drawable.smartphone,
        R.drawable.e_mail_envelope, R.drawable.facebook_logo, R.drawable.map_localization,
        R.drawable.grid_world};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    tvDetails=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11);
    //final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContact);


    ArrayList<addValuesContact> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContact);
    lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapterContact(this, searchResults));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            addValuesContact fullObject = (addValuesContact) o;
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have chosen: " + " " + fullObject.getDetails(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

private ArrayList<addValuesContact> GetSearchResults() {
    ArrayList<addValuesContact> results = new ArrayList<>();
    addValuesContact sr1 = new addValuesContact();

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        sr1.setImage(icons[i]);
        sr1.setTv1(desc[i]);
        sr1.setDetails(details[i]);
        results.add(sr1);
    }

    return results;
}}
```

My Custom adapter class details is given below

```
public class MyCustomAdapterContact extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<addValuesContact> searchArrayList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapterContact(Contextcontext,ArrayList<addValuesContact>results) {
    searchArrayList = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.tvDetails (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    addValuesContact bean = (addValuesContact)searchArrayList.get(position);

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(bean.getImage());
    holder.tvDetails.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDetails());
    holder.tv1.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTv1());


    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView tvDetails;
    TextView tv1;

}}
```

Pojo class is given below

```
public class addValuesContact {
private String details = "";
private String tv1 = "";
int image;
public int getImage() {
return image;
}
public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}

public String getTv1() {
    return tv1;
}

public void setTv1(String tv1) {
    this.tv1 = tv1;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}}
```

Comment: In your ContactUs activity try to move addValuesContact sr1 = new addValuesContact(); inside for loop.  in GetSearchResults()

Comment: @ajantha: thnks it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update below method:

```
private ArrayList<addValuesContact> GetSearchResults() {
    ArrayList<addValuesContact> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        addValuesContact sr1 = new addValuesContact();
        sr1.setImage(icons[i]);
        sr1.setTv1(desc[i]);
        sr1.setDetails(details[i]);
        results.add(sr1);
    }

    return results;
}
```

**Reason:** You need to create new object of your model class everytime.

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

For creating a list with all the items available in the array you need to create an object of your model class everytime you traverse into a loop for setting the data. So add `addValuesContact sr1 = new addValuesContact();` in for loop before setting the variables.

```
private ArrayList<addValuesContact> GetSearchResults() {
ArrayList<addValuesContact> results = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    addValuesContact sr1 = new addValuesContact();
    sr1.setImage(icons[i]);
    sr1.setTv1(desc[i]);
    sr1.setDetails(details[i]);
    results.add(sr1);
}

return results;
```

}